# Error in searching for an array data type string within a range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array of strings. I also had a worksheet containing two columns, first column contains the strings from my array and the second column contains the numeric code associated with the first column.
I need for a subset of the array to find, their associated codes. I tried the following but it does not work.

```
 Dim Data(1000, 1000) as string

.Range("B:B").Find(what:=Data(j,1), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

I checked to see why I get error and I noticed it does not recognize Data(j,1) as it's string value. The value in Data(j,1) (for j=1) is Sch_agr_Tor. If I replace Data(j,1) with the string "Sch_agr_Tor" it is fine, however that's not practical as I want to use the loop and cannot manually use "find".

In the immediate window I checked and got the following:

```
? TypeName(Data(j,1))
String
? Data(j,1)
Sch_agr_Tor
? Data(j,1)="Sch_agr_Tor"
False
? Data(j,1)=Sch_agr_Tor
False
```

I thought it might be internal bug of the Find. So I wrote my own find function.

```
Function FindRow(Rng As Range, Exp As String) As Long
  Dim vArr As Variant
  Dim j As Long
  Dim n As Long
  Dim c As Range
  n = 0
  For Each c In Rng

     If Exp = c.value Then
         n = c.Row
         Exit For
     End If

  Next c
 FindRow = n

End Function
```

However now when I change "Exp As String" argument in the FindRow function to "Exp As Variant" it will returns zero.

```
n = FindRow(UserSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count,  2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)), Data(j, 1))
```

If I enter

```
 n = FindRow(UserSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count,  2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)), "Sch_agr_Tor")
```

I get the right answer which is 39. 
Here is the header and the rest of the code:

```
Option Explicit

Option Base 1

Sub main()



Dim MainWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MainSheet, UserTableSheet, InputSheet, OutputSheet, TradesSheet,  InitialSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetCellLoc As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim addressName As String
Dim originCellLoc, Str As String
Dim i, j, NumRuns As Integer
Dim t_start, t_end As Double
Dim FirstCol, LastCol, n As Integer
Dim Data() As Variant



' Initialize the variables
 Set MainWorkbook = Application.ThisWorkbook
 Set InitialSheet = MainWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 Set MainSheet = MainWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")




 i = 2
 Do While MainSheet.Cells(11, i).value <> ""
 Set UserTableSheet = MainWorkbook.Sheets(MainSheet.Cells(11, i).value)
 Set InputSheet = MainWorkbook.Sheets(MainSheet.Cells(12, i).value) 

 With InputSheet
 FirstCol = .Range("1:1").Find(what:="Collateral Agreement Group:",  LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False).Column
 LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  End With

 'creating an array for our data with the right dimension
  ReDim Data(LastCol - FirstCol + 1, 6)


  For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)

  Data(j, 1) = Mid(InputSheet.Cells(1, FirstCol + j - 1).value, 28, 1 +  Len(InputSheet.Cells(1, FirstCol + j - 1).value) - 28)
  MainWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 1) = Data(j, 1) 

 n = FindRow(UserTableSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)), Data(j, 1))


  Data(j, 2) = UserTableSheet.Cells(n, 4)

  Next j


  i = i + 1
   Loop

  End Sub
```

Comment: What error did you get and what are you calling `.Range` on?

Comment: The error is Type mismatch. There are parents prior to range which refer to the right sheet.

Comment: You should probably post the code in more context then.  I can't replicate the error with the code above.

Comment: Main question is why "Data(1,1)" is not equal to its intrinsic value. It is holding the string "Sch_agr_Tor" but vba recognize them differently.

Comment: The edit is a completely different question.  I meant the code between `Dim Data(1000, 1000) as string` and `.Range("B:B").Find`.  Note that the line of code you originally posted shouldn't even compile without an assignment.

Comment: Did you Trim() the strings before you loaded the array?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the correct *Worksheet.*  This adaptation of your code appears to work:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim Data(1000, 1000) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Data(1, 1) = "Sch_agr_Tor"
    j = 1
    Set r = Range("B:B").Find(what:=Data(j, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
    MsgBox r.Row
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Other than being on the correct worksheet, there are two other things that might go wrong:

- starting from the wrong location
- trying to match a whole cell instead of part of the cell

For example:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim Data(1000, 1000) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Data(1, 1) = "Sch_agr_Tor"
    j = 1

    Set r = Range("B:B").Find( _
        what:=Data(j, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        After:=Range("B1"), _
        LookAt:=xlPart)

    MsgBox r.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: You entering the string directly into the array. I don't know if that's why it make it correct. I posted the whole code.